# Check what website is my app displaying. It was created with appcreator24

Tags: applications, apk, internet

I have an app that is basically a container of a browser opening a website but I am unable to see what website it is so I can open it through a normal browser.

I have tried to trap the network traffic but haven't found a way to do so, and extracting the apk has given me too much files to check. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you link the app? Also, if you turn off the internet, does it stop loading?

Comment: I can't since it has personal information, but It does not load anything without internet, not even the interface, so I'm 100% positive it's a sanboxed browser

Comment: Usually such generated apps have fixed code and load the start URL from a configuration file. Unpack the APK, delete the dex files and make a full text search tool searching for `https://` assuming the site you configured is a https site or even longer parts of the URL that should be used. May be you find the URL, then you know the file.